# htmltext as object in flex

Tags: apache-flex, flex3, textarea, htmltext

is it possible to convert htmltext in object and move that object in textarea?

Regards,

Shivang

Comment: Can you give an example of what you're trying to do? You can assign html to the "htmlText" property of TextArea. (http://livedocs.adobe.com/flex/3/html/help.html?content=textcontrols_04.html)

Answer (score 1):

Do you mean running Javascript from inside the HTMLtext? I do not think that is possible. I may have misunderstood what you're trying to say though.

Comment: hi, thanks for quick reply. I want to move arrow image in textarea on click event or key down or up event. So for that i put image in htmltext. Now i want to move image on events. is it possible?

Comment: Hmmm... to do this, you have to use Actionscript to detect the event, and then use the event handler to modify the HTMLtext.

Comment: ya, thanks again. But how to detect and modify current htmltext. can u provide some detail information about it.

Comment: @shivang - can you give some more information on what you're trying to do?  For example, do you want to animate the image, or just change its location in the text?

Comment: @rhtx - Hi, I want to change location of image within textarea. Like, we see in other texteditors.